# Joining tables in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I am having trouble with a SQL query.

```
SELECT t.topicname, m. *, ms.avatar
   FROM `messages` m
    INNER JOIN topics t ON m.topicid = t.topicid
    inner join users u on m.author=u.username
    inner join misc ms on u.userid=ms.userid
   ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT 5
```

what i want to do is get the topicname from the topics table, everything from the messages table and avatar from the misc table

I join the topics and messages table by the topicid
I can join the messgages and users table by messages.author and users.username and to join to the misc table  i join on users.userid and misc.userid

The problem is I am not getting the results I want

This query works on the messages and topics tables joined but i need to add the misc table and the only way to join that is throught the users table

```
SELECT t.topicname, m. *
   FROM `messages` m
    INNER JOIN topics t ON m.topicid = t.topicid
    ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT 5
```

Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `messageid` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `boardid` int(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  `topicid` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `postdate` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`messageid`)
)

CREATE TABLE `misc` (
  `miscid` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userid` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  `profpic` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `avatar` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `signature` text NOT NULL,
  `alerts` enum('y','n') NOT NULL default 'y',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`miscid`)
)

CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `topicid` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `boardid` int(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  `topicname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `counter` int(5) NOT NULL default '0',
  `sticky` char(1) NOT NULL default 'n',
  `locked` char(1) NOT NULL default 'n',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`topicid`)
)

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userid` int(25) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `first_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `last_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`userid`)
)
```

This is the output of the query with only 2 joins and this is what i expect to get (only i want to have an avatar with it)

It doesn't llok to pretty here but that is what the database gives me

```
topicname         messageid       boardid         topicid         message         author      postdate
Mauris Eu Neque Ipsum   36  4   8   Suspendisse nibh risus, porta at cursus sed, tinci...   iTuneStinker    2010-04-08 20:31:39
Aliquam Erat Volutpat   35  5   15  Donec volutpat ligula eu lorem pharetra a adipisci...   AwsomeMoon  2010-04-07 21:58:20
Ut Non Risus Elit   34  2   14  Etiam cursus, erat sed placerat fringilla, risus a...   ScaryHair   2010-04-07 15:35:34
Quisque Rutrum Mattis Sagittis  33  5   9   Etiam in elit sit amet nulla scelerisque ultricies...   ScaryHair   2010-04-07 15:33:46
Where Do I Start Trying To Organise A Festival  32  3   12  Morbi a neque aliquam nisl varius lobortis. Sed ve...   ScaryHair   2010-04-07 13:27:40
```

and here is the result using the query that joins all tables

```
topicname         messageid       boardid         topicid         message         author      postdate        avatar
Forum Rules And Guidelines  2   1   1   FORUM RULES     AdRock  2009-04-11 23:05:18     avatar_17200.jpg
Forum Rules And Guidelines  3   2   2   FORUM RULES.    AdRock  2009-04-11 23:05:18     avatar_17200.jpg
Forum Rules And Guidelines  4   3   3   FORUM RULES     AdRock  2009-04-11 23:05:18     avatar_17200.jpg
Forum Rules And Guidelines  5   4   4   FORUM RULES     AdRock  2009-04-11 23:05:18     avatar_17200.jpg
Forum Rules And Guidelines  6   5   5   FORUM RULES     AdRock  2009-04-11 23:05:18     avatar_17200.jpg
```

The first quert gets the last 5 records of the messages table and that is what i want but i want to be able to get the avatar that relates to the author of each message

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. Please post what do you get and what do you want to get. Also please post the structure of `users`.

Comment: You are not getting expected result? What you get?

Comment: Why is the avatar, profpic & signature in a seperate table and not with the user table? From your last resulst, the avatar seems to be there `avatar_17200.jpg`? Is that what you are looking for because I can't seem to see why you are missing the avatar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you don't have users and avatars filled for each message.

Try replacing the `INNER JOINS` with the `OUTER JOINS`.

```
SELECT  t.topicname, m. *, ms.avatar
FROM    `messages` m
JOIN    topics t
ON      t.topicid = m.topicid
LEFT JOIN
        users u
ON      u.username = m.author
LEFT JOIN
        misc ms
ON      ms.userid = u.userid
ORDER BY
        m.postdate DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Many thanks

I think i tried that the other day and I was getting NULL for the avatar.  I know what was causing that and this now works.....many thanks