# MySQL multi-table query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Greetings! I'm having difficulties creating a query that references multiple tables. I'm new to SQL and joins are stumping me. I've mucked about Google and after searching around I discovered [Joining tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131862/joining-tables-in-sql) which got me closer to where I want to be! The query I've created isn't doing what I want. I have two tables:

```
disp_profile
    disp_id*  name      address      zip
    0001      Profile1  SomeAddress1 11111
    0002      Profile2  SomeAddress2 22222
    0003      Profile3  SomeAddress3 33333

zipcode
    zip_code* state     city         county
    11111     CA        City1        County1
    22222     WA        City2        County2
    33333     NV        City3        County3
```

What I am attempting to do is grab the City, State, County from zipcode when the zipcode.zip = disp_profile.zip (filtered by a variable State). Ideally returning something like:

```
    dispId    dispName     dispAddress     dispZip    zipState    zipCounty    zipCity  zipCode
    001       Profile1     SomeAddress1    11111      CA          County1      City1    11111
or
    002       Profile2     SomeAddress2    22222      WA          County2      City2    22222


SELECT
    dp.disp_id AS dispId, dp.name AS dispName, dp.address1 AS dispAddress1, dp.zip AS dispZip, zc.state AS zipState, zc.county AS zipCounty, zc.city AS zipCity, zc.zip_code AS zipCode
FROM
    disp_profile dp
INNER JOIN
    zipcodes zc
ON
    dp.zip = zc.zip_code
WHERE
    dp.state = 'CA'
```

I'm aware this may not be the best way to go about this but I thought it better to store things separately vs redundant information for each item. The dataset in disp_profile is about 1000 records and zip_codes is about 30,000. Would this be done easier with a subquery? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your output seems to be fine! I am not sure what is the error and what you want as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you are doing it fine**. This is what **joins where made for**, no need to use a subquery here. You could, but **it would not perform better** (the MySQL Query Optimizer might even translate it to a join internally).

If you worry about speed: Put the word "EXPLAIN" in front of your SELECT statement to see what MySQL is doing:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    dp.disp_id AS dispId, dp.name AS dispName, dp.address1 AS dispAddress1, dp.zip AS dispZip, zc.state AS zipState, zc.county AS zipCounty, zc.city AS zipCity, zc.zip_code AS zipCode
FROM
    disp_profile dp
INNER JOIN
    zipcodes zc
ON
    dp.zip = zc.zip_code
WHERE
    dp.state = 'CA'
```

It will tell you how your statement is being executed. Paste the output here if you want us to help interpreting :)

Comment: Thank you for your input. The query is correct, however the issue was my zipcode data being incomplete. Rookie mistake! Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

That looks okay to me, at least at first glance. I prefer the old school way of:

```
select dp.disp_id AS dispId,
       dp.name AS dispName,
       dp.address1 AS dispAddress1,
       zc.state AS zipState,
       zc.county AS zipCounty,
       zc.city AS zipCity,
       zc.zip_code AS zipCode
from   disp_profile dp,
       zipcodes zc
where  dp.state = 'CA'
  and  dp.zip = zc.zip_code
```

but that's just a matter of style (and using a DBMS with a very intelligent optimiser - whether MySQL is a match for my DBMS of choice, I couldn't comment (but I doubt it)).

The one change I *have* made (and which you probably should) is to only get *one* of the ZIP codes. It's redundant getting the field from both `dp` and `zc` since they're identical due to your join.

Comment: Funny, when I use this JOIN style, I get [lectured for using the old syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291116/selecting-with-two-references-to-same-table/5291142#5291142) ;)

Comment: I just find the old syntax more understandable but it's probably because the number of times I've actually had to use all those right, outer, upside-down, slightly oblique joins, I can count on the fingers of one foot :-)

Comment: Paxdiablo, thanks for your solution. It works, however the mistake lies entirely on my end. The zipcode data I have is incomplete and explains the funky behavior. Thank you very much for your time!